# How to do operations on duration in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so i did a survey and collected some data about bedtime, wake-up time and calculated the total time in spent on sleep in the form of duration. now i wanna use that duration to do some operations on it to calculate sleep dept. i need the duration - 10, this is just my survey was done by school kids who were 12 years old and they need at least 10 hours of sleep everyday.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jIME.png)

this is currently what i have and the error i get is

"Function MINUS parameter 2 expects number values. But 'Total Amount of sleep (hrs)' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since hours are stored as fractions of days (24h), you can do

```
=C2-10/24
```

Or you can use the TIME function.

```
=C2-TIME(10,0,0)
```